# proving validity of propositions(logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

i'm stuck for quite a while with those two questions. would appreciate your assistance with them:

1)$\varphi \models \psi$  then $\varphi$ is contradiction or $\psi$ is a tautology, or there exists elementary proposition in both  $\varphi$ and $\psi$

2)show that if $\Gamma \:\cup \left\{\varphi \right\}⇒\psi$ and $\Gamma \:\cup \left\{\varphi \right\}⇒\lnot\psi$  then $\Gamma \models\lnot \varphi$

1)i don't see how $\varphi$ can be a contradiction, which means that $\varphi \models\psi$ must be an elementary proposition. however, i don't know how to prove or show that.

2)i don't understand the logic here. if the union gives that both $¬φ$ and $φ$, then it should be $Γ\models φ$. i don't understand that.

thank you very much for your help, maybe you can help me understand what i'm missing here and how to approach it correctly

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I will try to explain the intuition here.

1. $\varphi \models \psi$ is trivially true if $\varphi$ is a contradiction or $\psi$ is a tautology. (I don’t understand your comment at all... of course $\varphi$ can be a contradiction, it is pretty much an arbitrary statement.) What you are to show is that if neither of these trivial cases hold, then $\varphi$ and $\psi$ must share a proposition. In other words for $\psi$ to be a nontrivial logical consequence of $\varphi,$ it must have something to do with $\varphi.$ This shouldn’t be hard to believe. To prove it you need to show that if the statements don’t share a proposition, $\varphi$ is not a contradiction and $\psi$ is not a tautology, you can find an interpretation where $\varphi$ is true and $\psi$ is false.
2. The premise is that $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi\} $ is inconsistent. This may be either because $\Gamma$ is inconsistent, or because $\Gamma$ implies $\lnot \varphi$ so adding $\varphi$ yields an inconsistency. Either way $\Gamma\models \lnot\varphi.$ By explosion in the first case, and obviously in the second.

Comment: i don't understand the explanation for 2. could you please elaborate more a bit please? i understand that φ + ¬φ yields inconsistency, however how can i mathmatically deduct that $Γ⊨¬φ$?

Comment: @BeginningMath You need to show that if all the sentences in $\Gamma$ are true, then $\varphi$ is false. What you are given implies that $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent, i.e. there is no interpretation in which all the sentences in $\Gamma\cup \{\varphi\}$ are true. So what can we say about the truth of $\varphi$ in any interpretation where all the sentences in $\Gamma$ are true?

Comment: i understand the logic behind it, but i don't understand how to write it, that's what i meant. i understand that if all the sentences in Γ are true in relation to the truth of φ, then it must be that Γ defined iff ¬φ

Comment: @BeginningMath What does “$\Gamma$ defined iff $\lnot\phi$“ mean? What does “true in relation to the truth of $\phi$” mean?

Comment: @BeginningMath browsing some of your other questions, this seems to be a communication problem you have where you use loose synonyms instead of proper terms. At one point you refer to a proposition as “real”... do you mean “true?” If so, say “true.” Similarly here you say $\Gamma$ is “defined” which is not a standard term pertaining to a set of sentences. Do you mean all its sentences are true? If so, say that.

Comment: i understand and try to pass the language barrier, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @BeginningMath It’s okay. I’m fortunate that I haven’t had to learn math in a different language so I don’t know how hard it is to match up terminology.